# How to Join two tables in Hbase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

### Problem:

I  am new to Hbase and I came across a situation where I need to join two tables.
Let us suppose I have Employee table and Department table both are created  in Hbase. By reading Hbase in action , I got to know that we cannot join tables in Hbase.

### Solution:

I found out a solution that by writing MapReduce Code using Hbase classes and Interfaces we can achieve this task.

Also if someone can help me with the coding that would be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to load your HBase tables into [Hive](http://hortonworks.com/blog/hbase-via-hive-part-1/) or [Impala](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_impala_hbase.html) and perform a SQL join with those tools.

Comment: Thankyou for ur answer...  But that was not  the recommended solution. Need to perform Hbase mapreduce for Joins and also for aggregations.In case if u have any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

You should look at this jira issue in apache. You should use MultiTableInputFormat.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3996

See also: 
[how to join tables in hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327316/how-to-join-tables-in-hbase?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Using Hive or Impala is costly when data is to large and we face issue like Hbase kill(region server Down) . so it is convenient when data is small but not for large Data. In mapreduce take Hbase table object to take one table and by extending tablemapper use 2nd table. By this way you can join 2 tables.