# How to join two Hbase tables in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, sqoop

I have two tables in HBase that I need to join using scala. The tables are imported from Oracle using sqoop and are available for querying in the Hue data browser

Using Spark 1.5, Scala 2.10.4.

I'm using the HBase data connector from here: https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector

```
import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ HBaseAdmin, Result }
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{ HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor }
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.spark._
import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase.conversion.{ FieldReader, FieldWriter }
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

case class Artist(id: String,
                 name: String,
                 age: Int);

case class Cd(id: String,
              artistId: String,
              title: String,
              year: Int);

case class ArtistCd(id: String,
                    name: String,
                    title: String,
                    year: Int);

implicit def artistReader: FieldReader[Artist] = new FieldReader[Artist] {

    override def map(data: HBaseData): Artist = Artist(

        id = Bytes.toString(data.head.get),
        name = Bytes.toString(data.drop(1).head.get),
        age = Bytes.toInt(data.drop(2).head.get));

    override def columns = Seq("NAME", "AGE");

};

implicit def cdReader: FieldReader[Cd] = new FieldReader[Cd] {

    override def map(data: HBaseData): Cd = Cd(

        id = Bytes.toString(data.head.get),
        artistId = Bytes.toString(data.drop(1).head.get),
        title = Bytes.toString(data.drop(2).head.get),
        year = Bytes.toInt(data.drop(3).head.get));

    override def columns = Seq("ARTIST_ID", "TITLE", "YEAR");

};

implicit def artistCdWriter: FieldWriter[ArtistCd] = new FieldWriter[ArtistCd] {
    override def map(data: ArtistCd): HBaseData =
        Seq(
            Some(Bytes.toBytes(data.id)),
            Some(Bytes.toBytes(data.name)),
            Some(Bytes.toBytes(data.title)),
            Some(Bytes.toBytes(data.year)));

    override def columns = Seq("NAME", "TITLE", "YEAR");
};

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBase Join").setMaster("spark://localhost:7337")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val artistRDD = sc.hbaseTable[Artist]("ARTISTS").inColumnFamily("cf")
val cdRDD = sc.hbaseTable[Cd]("CDS").inColumnFamily("cf")

val artistById = artistRDD.keyBy(f => f.id)
val cdById = cdRDD.keyBy(f => f.artistId)

val artistcd = artistById.join(cdById)

val artistCdRDD = artistcd.map(f => new ArtistCd(f._2._1.id, f._2._2.title, f._2._1.name, f._2._2.year))
artistCdRDD.toHBaseTable("ARTIST_CD").inColumnFamily("cf").save()
System.exit(1)
```

When I run this I get the following exception

```
16/01/22 14:27:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 3, localhost): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 2068 actions: ARTIST_CD: 2068 times,
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.makeException(AsyncProcess.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess$BatchErrors.access$1700(AsyncProcess.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.waitForAllPreviousOpsAndReset(AsyncProcess.java:1663)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.backgroundFlushCommits(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.doMutate(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:141)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.mutate(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:129)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:85)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1034)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1034)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1206)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1042)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1014)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If anyone has any experience in this, I'd really appreciate your help

I've seen the two solutions here [How to Join two tables in Hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589288/how-to-join-two-tables-in-hbase) and [how to join tables in hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327316/how-to-join-tables-in-hbase) and unfortunately neither is going to work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - first the new table needs to already exist. 
I had thought the save() command would create it, but no.
Also, the new table has to have the column family you're saving to - here "cf"

Answer (score 0):

example 1)

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path= {put apache lib path}:  {put hbase lib path}

spark-shell --driver-class-path=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec/jars/* :/usr/local/Cellar/hbase-1.4.9/lib/*
```

example 2)

```
spark-shell --driver-class-path=$SPARK_HOME:$(hbase classpath)
```